# convolution of two periodic functions

Tags: convolution, signal-processing

I convolute two periodic function:

$f(x) = \sin(20 \cdot 2 \pi x)$

$g(x) = \sin(15 \cdot 2 \pi x)$

$h = f \ast g$

The function h consists of frequenzy portions of 5 *and* 35 HZ. 
I understand the 5 HZ peak (of the fourier transform), because of the reflection of the signal on the Nyquist frequency of 10 HZ.

Can someone explain why I get a peak at 35 HZ too?

Fourier transform of h:
[5 and 35 HZ peak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MLQc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you calculate that convolution? And exactly what sort of "convolution" do you mean? If you're talking about the default convolution for functions of period $1$, namely $$f*g(x)=\int_0^1f(x-t)g(t)\,dt,$$then the convolution of those two functions is $0$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
I used this formula:
$f \ast g(t) = 1/T \int_{0}^{T} f(\tau) \cdot g(t-\tau) d\tau$
I can provide my matlab code too, if it could help

Comment: Somewhere you need to set $T=1$ to get the actual convolution. Using matlab for that integral is a little sad - it's easy to work out. (Probably the easiest way to do the integral is to first write the sine in terms of complex exponentials.)

Comment: In any case, that convolution is $0$.